# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference,

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been getting this [java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference at com.appone.quicktext.UsersAdapter.getItemCount(UsersAdapter.java:46)]error and the app keeps crashing.

**User.java**

package com.appone.quicktext;

public class User {
private String uid, name, phoneNumber, ProfileImage;

```
public User(){}

public User(String uid, String name, String phoneNumber, String profileImage) {
    this.uid = uid;
    this.name = name;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    ProfileImage = profileImage;
}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public String getProfileImage() {
    return ProfileImage;
}

public void setProfileImage(String profileImage) {
    ProfileImage = profileImage;
}
```

}

**UserAdapter**

public class UsersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.UserViewHolder> {

```
Context context;
ArrayList<User> users;

public UsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> data){
    this.context = context;
    this.users = users;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_conversation,parent,false);
    return new UserViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserViewHolder holder, int position) {
    User user = users.get(position);
    holder.binding.username.setText(user.getName());
    Glide.with(context).load(user.getProfileImage())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.avatar)
            .into(holder.binding.profile);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return users.size();
}

public class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    RowConversationBinding binding;

    public UserViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        binding =RowConversationBinding.bind(itemView);
    }
}
```

}

**MainActivity.java**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ActivityMainBinding binding;
FirebaseDatabase database;
ArrayList<User> users;
UsersAdapter usersAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());



    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    users = new ArrayList<>();
    usersAdapter = new UsersAdapter(this, users);
    binding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(usersAdapter);

    database.getReference().child("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            users.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot1: snapshot.getChildren()){
                User user = snapshot1.getValue(User.class);
                users.add(user);
            }
            usersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

//        getSupportActionBar().hide();
}

Answer (score 4):

```
public UsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> data){
    this.context = context;
    this.users = users;
}
```

---

change

*this.users = users*

to

*this.users = data*